# PHPUnit fails with process isolation but passes without that flag

Tags: laravel, phpunit

My tests are running properly and all green when I run them without any particular flag:

```
phpunit --configuration /home/vagrant/code/phpunit.xml /home/vagrant/code/tests
```

When I enable process isolation, the tests are failing:

```
phpunit --configuration /home/vagrant/code/phpunit.xml /home/vagrant/code/tests --process-isolation
```

The error looks like this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/code/routes/web.php(6): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('get', Array)
#1 Standard input code(1653): require_once('/home/vagrant/c...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 234
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/code/routes/web.php(6): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('get', Array)
#1 Standard input code(1653): require_once('/home/vagrant/c...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 234
```

I already tried a few things from the 3 or 4 threads I found on Laracast or StackOverflow regarding that kind of exception but nothing works yet:

- Excluding routes from PHPUnit.xml
- Running phpunit from vendor/bin or the one included in the system
- etc.

Any idea about where to look for or check? I am running out of ideas.

Using latest Laravel 5.8 and PHPUnit 8.0.6

Comment: Have you tried to run them on your host machine but not in VM?

Comment: Yes. Same thing :/

Comment: May I ask you to try write a couple of dummy tests (something like `$this->assertTrue(true)`) and see if they run with `--process-isolation`?

Comment: Not all tests are failing. Some (most) are passing.

Comment: `php artisan config:cache`?

Comment: Can you try to disable global state with calling $this->setPreserveGlobalState(false); in the setUp() method?

Comment: Can you provide a simple test that fails with `--process-isolation`?

Comment: No config:cache is done. `$this->setPreserveGlobalState(false);` does not change anything (same result).

Comment: @VincentMimoun-Prat please check if this could help you. Process Isolation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077400/phpunit-not-continuing-with-tests-after-fatal-error-when-using-process-isolati

For laravel facade settings with unit test - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818102/laravel-5-6-uncaught-runtimeexception-a-facade-root-has-not-been-set

Comment: From the links you provide, I could suspect that maybe PHPUnit tries to load route files and execute them before the app is setup. Which would call the Route:: facade and cause that message.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would try is: run the failing test alone rather than against the entire tests folder.

Next, I would make sure if the failing test is calling [`setFacadeApplication()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php#L215) via [`createApplication()`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.7/tests/CreatesApplication.php#L18) or something similar. For instance, if `setUp()` doesn't call its parent `setUp()`, the static variable `$app` in Facade might not be set. That's the situation [the RuntimeException message says](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php#L234).

```
protected function setUp() // in your test case class
{
    // parent::setUp(); // it's necessary
}
```

Since it is static variable, once it's set its value would stay available among all the test cases without `--process-isolation`.

Comment: Running the failing test alone, with process isolation ON = it passes. The setUp functions are proper.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. I fixed it by creating a new app container and then binding it to the Facade.

```
use \Illuminate\Container\Container as Container;
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade as Facade;

/**
* Setup a new app instance container
* 
* @var Illuminate\Container\Container
*/
$app = new Container();
$app->singleton('app', 'Illuminate\Container\Container');

/**
* Set $app as FacadeApplication handler
*/
Facade::setFacadeApplication($app);
```

in lumen: bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->withFacades();
```